# Python Value Error:Need more than 1 value to unpack why this error

Tags: python-3.x

I write this code:

```
 while(1):
     a,b,c=input().split(" ")
     a=int(a)
     b=int(b)
     c=int(c)
     if(a==0):
         break
     else:
         d=a*b
         c=(d*100)/c
         f=c**(1/2.0)
         print(int(f))
```

but this error occured:

```
Traceback (most recent call last): File "Main.py", line 2, in
    a,b,c=input().split(" ")
ValueError: need more than 1 value to unpack
Command exited with non-zero status (1)
```

please anyone tell me why this error occured and I can I get rid from this error.

Comment: There are no spaces in the input.

Comment: @Ignacio Vazquez-Abrams  This is actually Uri online judge problem. and problem no 1541. when i run in python IDLE it correctly work but when i submit this on uri online judge its showing this error.

Sample Input is:
8 10 20
1 10 100
0 10 20

and this is the output:
20
3

Comment: Then you've misinterpreted the specifications.

Answer (score 1):

your error is explained in the error message:

> need more than 1 value to unpack

this means that werever your input function is returning, it does not have (at least) 2 spaces/tabs.

You expect to unpack 3 variables: `a,b,c`
so if there's no `split(" ")`, you can't get 3 values back...

This works...

```
def input():
  return "one two three"

a,b,c=input().split(" ")
```